# Whats the best way to implement a custom Calendar on the iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to create a calendar that will allow for events to be created and deleted within an iphone app. Can someone recommend a way to accomplish this and possibly mention existing apps that use this feature

Answer (score 1):

You could probably benefit a lot from the [Tapku Library](http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary).

It includes a calendar month and day views, which you could probably pair with Core Data or another persistence solution to get what you need.